# What is the lowest and highest number of pagination

Tags: algorithms

I am building a basic pagination bar to separate posts into pages. I have 3 numeric values:

```
$posts_per_page
$total_pages
$clicked_page_number
```

So for example, I have `31` posts. And my `$posts_per_page` value is `15`, which means that `$total_pages` becomes `3`.

My question is, how do I calculate the *lowest* and *highest* post number *of the selected page*?

To explain this, using the values above, if user clicks on page `2`, then tghe lowest post number is `16` and the highest post number is `30`.

Comment: This may be some entry-level stuff but my math skills are a bit rusty. =)

Comment: Are you familiar with the modulo function? Modular arithmetic?

Comment: On page $n$ you will have the range of posts as $[15n-14,15n]$.

Comment: In my example, i meant `31 posts`, not `31 pages`!

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the number of posts per page; $n_{\text{max}}$ the total number of posts and $n$ is the clicked page number.

When $n_{\text{max}} \leq p$, the analysis is easy: The first post is $1$ and the last one is $n_{\text{max}}$.

If $ n_{\text{max}} > p$, the posts will be distributed on different pages. In your example, the posts are distributed like so:
$$
31 = 15 + 15 + 1
$$
If there are many posts, how many are on the last page? The answer is the remainder of division between $n_{\text{max}}$ and $p$. Therefore, the post distribution in your example is
$$
[1\dots 15],\quad [16\dots 30], \quad [31]
$$
In general, we would have
$$
[1, \dots p], \quad [p+1 \dots 2p], \quad  [2p+1 \dots 3p], \quad  \dots \quad ,[n_{\text{max}}-b,n_{\text{max}}-b + 1, \dots n_{\text{max}} ]
$$
In this, I had to notate $b$ to be the remainder of the division. Usually, in programming,
$$
b = MOD(n_{\text{max}}, p)
$$
In practice you have to divide the analysis into the two cases like I did. Do you know how to do it now?

Comment: Additionally, if $b=MOD(n_{\max}, p) = 0$, the last page is "empty", in which case the previous page becomes the last page.